# FFMEPG permission problem, is there any alternative solution instead of FFMPEG?

Tags: windows, iis, permissions, ffmpeg, file-permissions

We have some kind of permenant permission problem on FFMPEG.exe to write JPEG file on to HDD.
We are using IIS and try all permission methods to ffmepg.exe, its including folder,folders, cmd.exe and any executable file, related folder, file. Also we tried many many command examples. But never went beyond the "permission denied" error messages.
We give up.
Do you know another alternative solution to pick images from flv, f4v movie files? Or %100 quaranteed method to achive this permission control on IIS?
Thank you.
---last code we try
  variables etc. aren't shown here.

```
jpegYapKomutu = videoEditorKlasoru &"\ffmpeg.exe -i " & videoEditorKlasoru & "\deneme.flv" &" -s 480×360 -ss 00:00:"&saniyesi&" -vframes 1 -f mjpeg "&  "C:\Webhome\normworks\caglarorhan\deneme.jpg"
        WScript.Run "%COMSPEC% /C dir" & jpegYapKomutu
```

Comment: Server W 2003 Enterprise Edition

Comment: Can you paste the full exception including stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely IIS is running under an anonymous account.  Try setting the Application Pool to run as a specific user account that has permission to execute ffmpeg.

[There's some info here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/)

Answer (score 1):

"Permission denied"-problems have nothing to do with FFMPEG, and you will get the same problems with any other tool.

By the way, this question probably belongs on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: OK, do you have any idea on what kind of permission adjust needed? I forgot to write, ffmpeg.exe succeed when used from command line...